# Laravel 8: Symbolic Link not appearing in public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, symlink

I have a problem with symlink. after I run this command `php artisan storage:link`
the uploaded images are showing in the public and storage folder.
I can display my img by using this code

```
<img src="{{ url('/storage/app/public/Attachments/test.png') }}" alt="">
```

but after a day **the shortcut of the images folder in public has gone** and when I run the `php artisan storage:link` it says it has been already linked.

my problem now is i cannot display the images.

i saw a similar question but it doesn't work for me. please help guys. thanks and staysafe.

Comment: what kind of access do you have to your server? are you using cpanel?

Comment: my website is for local use only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you are moving the project from one computer to another. When you copy the folders over to another machine, it sees the `symlink` folder as just another folder. So when you run `php artisan storage:link` it will just say that you already have the `symlink` created but your files won't display because the `shortcut to folder` or `symlink` does not actually exist.

Solution:

What you need to do is go to your public folder and delete the storage folder. Then run the php artisan command again and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

create a `.php` file in your public folder and put the following code and then visit the `.php` page from your web browser

```html
<?php

$target = '../storage/app/public';

$shortcut = '/storage';

symlink($target, $shortcut);

?>
```

now your `public/storage` folder will lead to `/storage/app/public`

Comment: hi, what can I name this .php file? can I name it anything? sorry I'm new to to this

Comment: Warning: symlink(): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\erp-web\public\symlink.php on line 7, this is my error sir

Comment: ok try to add the code to the end of your index.php file and run your Laravel main page

Comment: only add this line :     symlink('../storage/app/public', './storage');

Comment: symlink(): Permission denied, this is the error sir